# What is the difference between using and omitting keyword "await" in these two code blocks?

Tags: javascript

I'm following along an MDN article on async/await, and I understand the purpose of using the async keyword before functions, but I'm a little more confused about the await keyword. I've read up on on "await" as a result, and I get the general concept, but I'm still unsure when it comes to examples. For instance, here is a trivial piece of code (as shown in the MDN article) using async/await.

```
async function hello() {
  return greeting = await Promise.resolve("Hello");
};

hello().then(value => console.log(value));
```

As you might expect, this logs "Hello" to the console. But even if we omit "await", it has the exact same output.

```
async function hello() {
  return greeting = Promise.resolve("Hello"); // without await
};

hello().then(value => console.log(value));
```

Can someone help me understand exactly what the await keyword before Promise.resolve is doing? Why is the output the same even if it's omitted? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In up-to-date JavaScript engines, there's no difference, but only because the `return await somePromise` is at the top level of the function code. If it were within a control block (for instance, `try`/`catch`), it would matter.

This is a recent-ish change. Until ES2020 the `return await` version would have introduced an extra async "tick" into the process. But that was optimized out in a "normative change" (rather than proposal) in ES2020 when the promise being `await`ed is a native promise. (For a non-native thenable, there's still a small difference.)

For the avoidance of doubt, there's an important difference between:

```
async function example() {
    try {
        return await somethingReturningAPromise();
    } catch (e) {
        // ...do something with the error/rejection...
    }
}
```

and

```
async function example() {
    try {
        return somethingReturningAPromise();
    } catch (e) {
        // ...do something with the error/rejection...
    }
}
```

In the former, a rejection of the promise from `somethingReturningAPromise()` goes to the `catch` block, because it's been `await`ed. In the latter, it doesn't, because you've just returned the promise, which resolves the promise from the `async` function to the promise `somethingReturningAPromise()` returns, without subjecting it to the `catch`.

But in your example, where it's not in any control structure, the `await` is largely a matter of style at this point.

Comment: Is it best to still include it even when it's not needed?

Comment: @ILikeThePoopSmith - That's really a matter of style, since in the situations where it doesn't matter, it...doesn't matter. :-D I've tended to omitting the `await` when it doesn't matter, **but** that habit was formed prior to the ES2020 change. I think I should rethink that.

Comment: *(This is something that -- regrettably -- isn't clear enough in Chapter 9 of my recent book, JavaScript: The New Toys. But when I put the errata page up on https://thenewtoys.dev, I'll draw the distinction more clearly. But...er...the **rest** of the book is really clear and IMHO useful.)*

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that `async`/`await` is just a fancy API for working with promises.

An `async` function always and implicitly returns a promise (as soon as the first `await` or `return` statement is reached) that will be resolved when the function code itself finally reaches its end. The resolved promise value will be equal to the function's returned value.

`async` allows you to use `await` inside of the asynchronous scope. Await only makes sense when preceding a promise (could be another `async` function call, a promise created in place with `new Promise()`, etc.). Using `await` before non promise values will do no harm though.

`await` indicates, just that, wait. It tells the engine to 'stop' code execution on that scope and to resume it whenever the promise is fulfilled. `await` will then give you or 'return' the promise resolved value.

Just to give you some practical examples:

Using your first code:

```
async function hello() {
  const greeting = await Promise.resolve("Hello"); // HERE I CAN USE await BECAUSE I'M INSIDE AN async SCOPE.
  console.log('I will be printed after above promise is resolved.');
  return greeting;
};

hello().then(value => console.log(value));
```

Using your second code, `async` could be completely removed:

```
function hello() {
  return Promise.resolve("Hello");
};

hello().then(value => console.log(value));
```

Please let me know if there is any doubt.

Comment: *"Using your second code, `async` could be completely removed:"* Good point. In that specific example, since `await` is never used and there's no other `return` path, the `async` is unnecessary.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the clarification. You are right! I will edit my answer accordingly. Really liked your answer by the way, I didn't know you had answered when I sent mine.

Comment: There's plenty of room for multiple perspectives and ways of helping the OP. :-)